# Route 53 point different paths to different s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Is it possible to use Route 53 to point a path url like `mydomain.com/app` to a different s3 bucket than the one accessed by the rest of `mydomain.com`?

So for example:

`mydomain.com/*` would point to `normal-bucket`

`mydomain.com/app` would point to `app-bucket`

Is it necessary instead to just use a subdomain like `app.mydomain.com`?

Would a routing rule make this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, but not with route53 or DNS generally.

If you are using S3 static website hosting, you can use a redirect rule instead, to do HTTP redirects. See Amazon documentation for more information about that feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html

Here is an example of a routing rule that redirects to my-other-bucket on S3, where both the bucket with the rule and my-other-bucket are using static website hosting.

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>app</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <HostName>my-other-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com</HostName>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Comment: This configuration generates redirects, rewriting the browser's address bar and requiring a second HTTP request for each resource.  CloudFront provides the mechanism that allows multiple origins, which can be buckets or web servers, inside or outside of AWS, without redirects.

Answer (score 8):

You can create an [Amazon CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) distribution, then defining an origin for each of your Amazon S3 buckets. You can then define which path should use which origin.

See the (confusing) documentation page: [Values that You Specify When You Create or Update a Web Distribution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html)